# usort issue with decimal numbers

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm currently trying to sort a multidimensional array by its subvalues.
The structure of the array is:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 87
        [sold] => 50
        [stock] => 991
        [speed] => 1.5
        [days_left] => 660.66666666667
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 97
        [sold] => 20
        [stock] => 120
        [speed] => 1.2
        [days_left] => 100
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [sold] => 2
        [stock] => 1020
        [speed] => 1.02
        [days_left] => 1000
    )
```

The code I'm using is:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a[$_GET['sortby']] - $b[$_GET['sortby']]; });
```

where the $_GET['sortby'] variable equals the key.

So far so good, everthing is working, it sorts all values correctly EXCEPT the speed!
First, I thought it has something to do with the decimal numbers, but the days_left include also decimals and are sorted correctly.. :/

Correct output (days_left):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 97
        [sold] => 20
        [stock] => 120
        [speed] => 1.2
        [days_left] => 100
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 87
        [sold] => 50
        [stock] => 991
        [speed] => 1.5
        [days_left] => 660.66666666667
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [sold] => 2
        [stock] => 1020
        [speed] => 1.02
        [days_left] => 1000
    )
```

Wrong output (speed):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 97
        [sold] => 20
        [stock] => 120
        [speed] => 1.2
        [days_left] => 100
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 87
        [sold] => 50
        [stock] => 991
        [speed] => 1.5
        [days_left] => 660.66666666667
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [sold] => 2
        [stock] => 1020
        [speed] => 1.02
        [days_left] => 1000
    )
```

Hope anybody can help me!

Comment: Check your outputs .. they are 100% same at the moment..

Comment: Yes, they are, and this was the problem! They shouldn't be.. ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

See usort docs. Float result will be converted to integer. For correct work use this code:

```
usort(
    $data, 
    function($a, $b) {
        $result = 0;
        if ($a[$_GET['sortby']] > $b[$_GET['sortby']]) {
            $result = 1;
        } else if ($a[$_GET['sortby']] < $b[$_GET['sortby']]) {
            $result = -1;
        }
        return $result; 
    }
);
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the above code did not sort properly for me.  When I used the code in this answer, it did.  hopefully helps someone! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941137/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-decimal-values

Answer (score 3):

Try *strnatcmp()*:

```
usort($output, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($b->days_left, $a->days_left);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) and later you can simplify such cases with sorting float values by using `<=>` **spaceship operator** :

```php
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[$_GET['sortby']] <=> $b[$_GET['sortby']];
});
```

From PHP 7.4 you can also use [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) syntax with fn keyword:

```php
usort($data, fn($a, $b) => $a[$_GET['sortby']] <=> $b[$_GET['sortby']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The PHP doc has a comment that has the solution to this problem. A big thanks to that guy.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#42535)

Here is a function to sort multidimensional arrays with decimal numbers :

```
function usortWithFloatVals() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $array = $arguments[0];
    $code = '';
    for ($c = 1; $c < count($arguments); $c += 2) {
        if (in_array($arguments[$c + 1], array("ASC", "DESC"))) {
            $code .= 'if ($a["'.$arguments[$c].'"] != $b["'.$arguments[$c].'"]) {';
            if ($arguments[$c + 1] == "ASC") {
                $code .= 'return ($a["'.$arguments[$c].'"] < $b["'.$arguments[$c].'"] ? -1 : 1); }';
            }
            else {
                $code .= 'return ($a["'.$arguments[$c].'"] < $b["'.$arguments[$c].'"] ? 1 : -1); }';
            }
        }
    }
    $code .= 'return 0;';
    $compare = create_function('$a,$b', $code);
    usort($array, $compare);
    return $array;
}
```

Use it just like how you use `usort()` :

```
usortWithFloatVals($data, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a[$_GET['sortby']] - $b[$_GET['sortby']]) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In case someone wants a more concise code

using `ceil` will round fractions up and will sort the decimal numbers correctly

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) 
      {
        return ceil($a[$_GET['sortby']] - $b[$_GET['sortby']]); 
      });
```

Comment: Sorry, but ceil will not help to sort [2.2, 2.1, 2.5, -1.7, -1.8] in correct order.