# Why can this usort() function not properly sort decimals?

Tags: php, usort

Why are decimals not properly sorted:

```
13
11
14
10
12.5
---------------------------------------------------------
descending order:
14
12.5
13
11
10
```

with this code:

```
class Customer {
    public $score;
    public function __construct($score) {
        $this->score = $score;
    }
}

$customers = [];
$customers[] = new Customer(13);
$customers[] = new Customer(11);
$customers[] = new Customer(14);
$customers[] = new Customer(10);
$customers[] = new Customer(12.5);

if(is_array($customers) && count($customers) > 0)
{
    foreach($customers as $customer)
    {
        echo '<div>'.$customer->score.'</div>';
    }
}

echo '<hr/>';
echo '<div>descending order:</div>';
usort($customers, function($a, $b) {
    return $b->score - $a->score;
});


if(is_array($customers) && count($customers) > 0)
{
    foreach($customers as $customer)
    {
        echo '<div>'.$customer->score.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520000/usort-issue-with-decimal-numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting decimal `0.5` to integer changes it to `0`. Change your usort function to:

```
usort($customers, function($a, $b) {
    if($b->score - $a->score >= 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
});
```

Output:

```
descending order:
14
13
12.5
11
10
```

PHP Manual says:

> **Caution:** Returning non-integer values from the comparison function,
>   such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the
>   callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be
>   cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as
>   equal.

Comment: If you're already running PHP7, you can take advantage of the new "spaceship" operator and make the callback `return $b->score <=> $a->score;`

Comment: usort() should be able to return **THREE** values. <0, 0, or >0. you're not returning 0 (equal), just greater-/less-than.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
usort($customers, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($b->score,$a->score);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @hvtruong, you save my lot of time

Answer (score -1):

```
usort($customers, function($a, $b) {
    return (int)$b->score - (int)$a->score;
});
```

For example your input is `14.9,14` and `14.5` and the output as `14.9,14` and `14.5`, it's treated as, `14.9=14,14.0=14` and `14.5=14`